# Set a DTD using minidom in python

Tags: python, xml, dtd, minidom

I am trying to include a reference to a DTD in my XML doc using minidom.

I am creating the document like:

```
doc = Document()
foo = doc.createElement('foo')
doc.appendChild(foo)
doc.toxml()
```

This gives me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<foo/>
```

I need to get something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!DOCTYPE something SYSTEM "http://www.path.to.my.dtd.com/my.dtd">
<foo/>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The documentation is out of date. Use the source, Luke. I do it something like this.

```
from xml.dom.minidom import DOMImplementation

imp = DOMImplementation()
doctype = imp.createDocumentType(
    qualifiedName='foo',
    publicId='', 
    systemId='http://www.path.to.my.dtd.com/my.dtd',
)
doc = imp.createDocument(None, 'foo', doctype)
doc.toxml()
```

This prints the following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?><!DOCTYPE foo  SYSTEM \'http://www.path.to.my.dtd.com/my.dtd\'><foo/>
```

Note how the root element is created automatically by createDocument(). Also, your 'something' has been changed to 'foo': the DTD needs to contain the root element name itself.

Comment: Nice.  Glad you found a solution!

Answer (score 1):

According to [the Python docs](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.dom.minidom.html#minidom-and-the-dom-standard), there is no implementation of the DocumentType interface in the minidom.